# Is it possible to use Maybe with Extensible Records?

Tags: elm

I am trying to write a function to pull the maybe off a list of extensible records, I am wondering if this is possible. Source code is below, or see Ellie link [here](https://ellie-app.com/XVwxXqdVa1/0)

```
module Temp exposing (..)

import Html exposing (text)


main =
    text "Hello"


items : Maybe List { data | id : Int } -> List { data | id : Int }
items maybeList =
    case maybeList of
        Just t ->
            t

        Nothing ->
            []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Maybe List { data | id : Int }` parses as `Maybe (List) ({ data | id : Int })`. I'm not sure why the error message is so misleading, but the fix is to wrap `List ...` in `()` like this:

```
items : Maybe (List { data | id : Int }) -> List { data | id : Int }
              ^                        ^
```

Edit: also, your function can be simplified using `Maybe.withDefault`:

```
items = Maybe.withDefault []
```